# Странная работа scanner.nextInt()

Tags: java

Всем привет. Я совсем новичок и все утро ломаю голову над таким вопросом. 
К примру, простая программа, которая записывает вопросы и ответы в массив:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class proba {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input the number of cards:");
        int skolko = scan.nextInt();
        String[] vopros = new String[skolko];
        String[] otvet = new String[skolko];
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < skolko; i++) {
            System.out.println("The card #" + (i + 1) + ":");
            vopros[i] = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("The definition of the card #" + (i + 1) + ":");
            otvet[i] = scan.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Если переменную `int skolko` записывать в программу (`int skolko = 3;`) то программа работает адекватно и запрашивает по очереди вопрос / ответ ровно 3 раза.

```
The card #1:
<<
The definition of the card #1:
<<
```

Если переменную `skolko` вводить через `int skolko = scan.nextInt();`, то программа сперва просит ввести цифру, а потом сразу выводит

```
The card #1:
The definition of the card #1:
<
```

то есть ввода значения, после `The card #1:` не происходит и для `card #1` присваивается пустое значение (`""`).

Почему так?

Answer (score 10):

**Причина проблемы:**

Сначала нужно понять как работает `scanner.nextLine()`. Он дочитывает строку (по факту, он движется по массиву байт из `InputStream` консоли, т.е. из `System.in`) до её конца (до `\n`, либо `\r\n`, в зависимости от среды), после чего останавливается на первом же символе после символа(ов) конца строки, а все что он прочитал (за исключением символа(ов) конца строки он возвращает в качестве результата вызова).

Перед `for` вы вызываете `scanner.nextInt()`, который считывает число из `InputStream` консоли и останавливает свой указатель на первым же символе после окончания числа, в вашем случае, т.к. после ввода числа вы нажали `enter` у вас там находится символ(ы) перевода строки.

На первой итерации `for` у вас вызывается `scanner.nextLine()`, который согласно вышеописанному механизму читает все символы до конца строки и останавливается, но в вашем случае он уже стоял на символе конца строки, поэтому он просто сдвинул свой указатель на первый же символ после символа(ов) конца строки и остановился, а в результате своего вызова вернул пустую строку (`""`).

**Решение проблемы:**

Самый простой для вас способ: написать `scanner.nextLine();` сразу же после вызова `scanner.nextInt();` для перевода `scanner` на следующую строку (указатель в считываемом `InputStream` смещается на первый символ после символа(ов) конца текущей строки), где ввод символа контра строки еще не был осуществлен (т.к. её ввод, вообще, еще не был осуществлен).

**Пример альтернативного варианта использования nextInt:**

На основании вопросов из комментариев приведу пример, поясняющий как еще можно работать с методом `nextInt`:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите три числа в одну строку, разделенные пробельными символами:");
        System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
        System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
        System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
    }
}
```

Как видите, не обязательно выполнять `nextLine` после каждого `nextInt`, вы можете за раз из одной строки прочитать несколько чисел, разделенных пробельными символами.

**Рекомендации:**

В рамках Java для наименования классов согласно [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) принято использовать стиль UpperCamelCase (например, `Proba`), а не lowerCamelCase, как у вас (`proba`).

Comment: Большое спасибо. Получается, что scan.nextLine(); и scan.nextInt(); работают по разному? Int всегда требует, чтобы после него очистили строку маркером scan.nextLine();, а scan.nextLine();, при считывании строки этого не требует т.к. дочитывает строку до конца?

Comment: @Ilya, на самом деле, они работают очень схоже, просто у них разные алгоритмы остановки чтения байтов из `InputStream`: `nextLine` читает все символы до конца строки, а `nextInt` пропускает все пробельные символы начиная с текущей позиции до первого символа числа, затем читает до тех пор пока идут числовые символы (останавливается, когда встречает пробельный символ или символ перевод строки, иначе падает с исключением).

Comment: @Ilya, отвечая на вопрос касательно `nextLine` после каждого `nextInt`: посмотрите, пожалуйста, в конец ответа, я его дополнил информацией касательно альтернативного use-case `nextInt`.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз. Всё понял и разобрался.

Comment: @Ilya, если мой (или любой другой ответ) ответ помог вам решить проблему, то лучше пометить его, как "решение", иначе другим участникам stack overflow данный вопрос будет отображать как "нерешенный" и они будут зря отвлекаться на него.