# Заполнение матрицы scanner'ом. Один scanner работает не верно

Tags: java, массивы

Необходимо заполнить строковую матрицу данными пользователя. Двумерный массив - обязательное условие.
При использовании одного объекта сканера пропускается элемент arr[0][0]. Остальные элементы заполняются корректно.
Код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    getTwoDimensionalArray();
  } 
  
  public static String[][] getTwoDimensionalArray() {
    System.out.println("Введите количество строк и столбцов таблицы через пробел");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[][] arr = new String[sc.nextInt()][sc.nextInt()];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
          System.out.println("Введите ФИО");
          arr[i][j] = sc.nextLine();
        } else if (j % 2 != 0) {
          System.out.println("Введите баланс");
          arr[i][j] = sc.nextLine();
        }
      }
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[i]));
    }
    sc.close();
    return arr;
  }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Введите количество строк и столбцов таблицы через пробел
 3 2
Введите ФИО
Введите баланс
 fgh
[, fgh]
Введите ФИО
 cvb
Введите баланс
 cvb
[cvb, cvb]
Введите ФИО
 cvb
Введите баланс
 cvb
[cvb, cvb]
 12
```

Но если добавить еще один объект сканера, то все работает как надо:

```
public static String[][] getTwoDimensionalArray() {
    System.out.println("Введите количество строк и столбцов таблицы через пробел");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[][] arr = new String[sc.nextInt()][sc.nextInt()];
    
    Scanner line = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
          System.out.println("Введите ФИО");
          arr[i][j] = line.nextLine();
        } else if (j % 2 != 0) {
          System.out.println("Введите баланс");
          arr[i][j] = line.nextLine();
        }
      }
      // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[i]));
    }
    line.close();
    sc.close();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[0]));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[1]));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[2]));
    return arr;
  }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [`Scanner` не считывает строку после `nextInt()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526818/); [Особенности использования `scanner.nextLine()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/); [Странная работа `scanner.nextInt()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1108338/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это достаточно известная проблема, как указано в комментарии с дубликатами.

Она связана с особенностями реализации методов сканнера `nextInt`/ `nextDouble` / `next`, которые *оставляют* пробельный разделитель, включая символ строки, в потоке.

Но для решения данной проблемы ещё один экземпляр сканера *на потоке ввода* не нужен, достаточно обработать разделитель -- символ пустой строки, остающийся после `sc.nextInt()`:

```java
String[][] arr = new String[sc.nextInt()][sc.nextInt()];
// пропустить "пустую" строку
if (sc.hasNextLine()) sc.nextLine();
```

Другой вариант -- одинаково обрабатывать **весь** ввод, не смешивая `nextInt` c `nextLine`, в данном случае, лучше прочитать строку с числами при помощи `nextLine`, применяя к ней либо отдельный сканер:

```java
System.out.println("Введите количество строк и столбцов таблицы через пробел");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner nums = new Scanner(sc.nextLine());
String[][] arr = new String[nums.nextInt()][nums.nextInt()];
```

либо `String::split + Integer::parseInt`:

```java
System.out.println("Введите количество строк и столбцов таблицы через пробел");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] nums = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");
String[][] arr = new String[Integer.parseInt(nums[0])][Integer.parseInt(nums[1])];
```