# Ввод с клавиатуры данных разных типов

Tags: java

Всем привет! Учусь работать с ArrayList-ом. Задача такая: добавляем элементы в список, и после того как ввели последний нужный элемент нужно закончить добавление. Решил этот вопрос через цикл while. Но столкнулся с проблемой: Для выхода из цикла нужно нажать какую-то клавишу. В идеале хотел выходом с цикла сделать нажатие пробела(Spacebar), но если я правильно понял по тому, что начитался на просторах интернета - это очень сложно. Так как программа учебная, решил сделать выход через символ(букву). И при выводе на консоль столкнулся с InputMismatchException. Начал пересматривать инфу которую уже знаю и гуглить, но еще больше себя запутал. Может кто подскажет, как обойти это исключение? сделать правильно? или даже прописать выход с цикла с помощью пробела? Спасибо всем, кто подскажет и научит!

```
    while (true) {
        int number = scan.nextInt();
        list.add(number);
        String out = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        if("i".equals(out)){
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
```

Это кусок кода. Принцип работы такой:  int number принимает наши числа, а когда нам "надоело" их вводить - мы нажимаем клавишу "i", цикл прерывается и в консоль выводит наш list.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования `scanner.nextLine()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/); [`Scanner` не считывает строку после `nextInt()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526818/); [Заполнение матрицы scanner'ом. Один scanner работает не верно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1538748/)

Comment: Вы столкнулись с одной из самых популярных проблем у новичков.  Чтобы прочитать символ после чтения числа с помощью `nextInt`, следовало использовать `next`, а не `nextLine`

Comment: Если же хотите использовать именно `nextLine` для ввода каждого числа с отдельной строки, НЕ нужно использовать `nextInt`, а читаете ввод построчно -- тогда вы сможете проверить и пробел/пустую строку как условие выхода.

Comment: Чтобы прочитать символ после чтения числа с помощью nextInt, следовало использовать next, а не nextLine - я так делал, но в таком случае массив выводится в консоль через один, или же опять исключение. Например при вводе 1,2,3 - вывод в консоль: 1,3; а при вводе 1.2.3.4 - исключение.

Comment: В обоих последних примерах данные не будут читаться для сканера, который по умолчанию использует пробельные символы как разделители.

Comment: Придумал такое решение:        boolean bool = true;
        while (bool) {
            String input = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            if (Character.isDigit(input.charAt(0))) {
                list.add(Integer.valueOf(input));
            } if(input.equals("q")) {
                bool = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);  Приветствуется такое решение или очень большой код?  Оцените пожалуйста. И, если это возможно, подскажите могу ли я вместо символа выбрать другую клавишу( например -пробел). Если да, то как это сделать?

Comment: Разумеется в таком решении вы можете выбрать и пробел вместо буквы `'q'`, но дело в том, что после пробела всё равно придётся нажимать Enter, чтобы была введена _строка_.  Также в этом коде нет "защиты" от кривого ввода (может быть исключение при парсинге числа).

Comment: Можете посмотреть [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1551403/386633)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если стоит задача просто ввести целые числа в список, достаточно придерживаться однородного подхода:

1. Использовать `Scanner::nextInt` (+ дополнительно проверять поток ввода `Scanner::hasNextInt`)
2. Использовать построчный ввод `Scanner::nextLine` + `Integer.parseInt / Integer.valueOf(String str)`

Важно помнить, что по умолчанию разделителями в сканере являются только пробельные символы типа `' '`, `'\t'`, `'\n'`.  Если ввод содержит другие разделительные символы, например, знаки пунктуации `','`, `'.'`, `';'`, сканер придётся дополнительно сконфигурировать при помощи метода [`Scanner::useDelimiter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.lang.String-).

Примеры.

1. Ввод размера списка/массива и последующее заполнение.
   Достаточно использовать только метод `Scanner::nextInt`:

```java
public static List<Integer> readIntList(Scanner scan) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Введите количество целых чисел: ");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Введите " + n + " чисел через пробел");
    while (n-- > 0) {
        list.add(scan.nextInt());
    }
    return list;
}
```

2. Ввод списка произвольной длины, пока не будет обнаружено некоторое число -- признак конца ввода (0 для ввода натуральных чисел, -1 -- для ввода неотрицательных чисел и т.п.)

```java
public static List<Integer> readIntList(Scanner scan, int limit) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Вводите целые числа, пока не будет введено число " + limit + " -- признак конца ввода");
    int n;
    while ((n = scan.nextInt()) != limit) {
        list.add(n);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Как видно, оба метода достаточно просты благодаря тому, что используются одинаковые методы как для ввода основного содержимого списка, так и для ввода "ограничителей".

3. Ввод списка чисел произвольной длины, пока не будет введена команда выхода (слово или буква)
   Фактически, это исправленный вариант начального кода.
   Для организации выхода будет использоваться особое *множество* слов `Set<String> stopWords`.
   Если же пользователь введёт "непонятное" слово или число, они будут проигнорированы.

```java
public static List<Integer> readIntList(Scanner scan, Set<String> stopWords) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Вводите целые числа, пока не будет введено одно из слов: " + stopWords);
    while (true) {
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            list.add(scan.nextInt());
        } else if (scan.hasNext()) {
            if (stopWords.contains(scan.next().toLowerCase())) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

4. Обработка построчного ввода, пока не будет введена пустая строка или же строка, содержащая *только пробелы*.
   Здесь будет использоваться `Scanner::nextLine`, для простоты примем, что каждое число вводится в своей строке:

```java
public static List<Integer> readIntListByLine(Scanner scan) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Введите список целых чисел, каждое в своей строке, конец ввода -- пустая строка");
    String line;
    while (!(line = scan.nextLine().trim()).isEmpty()) { // trim() уберёт пробелы
        try {
            list.add(Integer.valueOf(line));
        } catch (NumberFormatException numfex) {
            // numfex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Аналогично можно реализовать проверку на ввод команды для прекращения ввода.

Comment: Доходчиво и красиво! Спасибо!